# Java Cannot find Login Processing url

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to complete a login system but when I log in, I get the following error

- "HTTP Error 404 CANNOT FIND "http://localhost:8181/user_login"

I know this obviously means cannot find it, but I'm confused on why it can't find it.
Here is my security config

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class UserSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

protected void user(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/user_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/success")
                .failureUrl("/login?error==true")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()

            ;
}        
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configurationGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
   }
```

And the login form

```
<form:form name='user' action="/user_login" method='POST'>

             <form:errors path="username" />
    
      <label for="username">Email address</label>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" name='username' value='' placeholder="Enter Email address"></td>
            <label for="password">Password: </label>
            <input type='password' class="form-control" name='password' /></td>
       
        
<input name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
        

</form:form>
```

Here is my other security for Admin that works

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class AdminSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("admin").password("12345").roles("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .withUser("tester").password("56789").roles("ADMIN");
        
    }
 
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/newUser")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login1")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true) 
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()

            ;
}

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea or tips to solve this issue I would be very grateful. Thank you Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is incorrect way for defining spring-security configuration, when you use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` you should use method overrides for definening custom settings, because spring doesn't know how to find that method:

```
protected void user(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/user_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/success")
                .failureUrl("/login?error==true")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()

            ;
}
```

Цorking versionЖ

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class UserSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/user_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/success")
                .failureUrl("/login?error==true")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**United version:**
I am using spring-security 5.4.2

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/newUser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .failureUrl("/login?error==true")
                .successHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> {
                    Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
                    if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/admin");
                    } else {
                        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/success");
                    }
                })
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("{noop}12345").roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("tester").password("{noop}56789").roles("ADMIN");
    }

}
```

I tested login possibilities, and all works, of course we cannot support two different `defaultSuccessUrl`, because http mapping(`HttpSecurity`) is single instance, and which config will be loaded first, that `defaultSuccessUrl` will be used for login form.
I omit `loginPage` config, and I don't think, that we can support both login pages, the same like for `defaultSuccessUrl` config.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm afraid that still isn't working. I have order as I have an @Order(1) for my admin login that works fine. I'll add that to the question to stop confusion. Have you got any other ideas on what I can do to fix it?

Comment: I think, you should unite two security configs in single class, because I expect collision of two ```WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter``` typed classes

Comment: I updated answer, please check common config, does it suit you?

Comment: Thank you for your help, the answer works perfectly

Comment: I'm glad that it turned out!